# Interaction with HTML forms on a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to figure out how to write a native ios app that allows me to push data into elements of a website.  For example, if a webpage has a text field, I would like to place a slider bar on top of the UIWebView, and have the result of the slider bar, say 5.0, be placed in the text field.  I have been trying to do with the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    NSString *scriptFunction = @"document.getElementById('user_field').value = 'Joe';";
    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptFunction];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
}
```

I get the result to print out 'Joe' to the console, but it does not update the text element on the web page.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  With this in my HTML document:

```
<form>
    First name: <input id="input1" type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input id="input2" type="text" name="lname"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And with this iOS code in UIWebViewDelegate.webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
NSString    *scriptFunction = @"document.getElementById( 'input1' ).value = 'Joe';";
NSString    *result         = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptFunction];
NSLog( @"Result: %@", result );
```

My UIWebView subclass also implements the UIWebViewDelegate.

In the WebView on the simulator, I see "Joe" appear in the "First name:" field.
My first try used 'fname' in getElementById().  When that did not work, I added the id="input1" to the HTML and switched to 'input1' in getElementById().  I also see the "Result: Joe" logged to my console.

Do I have something different in HTML (or other code) than yours?

Comment: I don't see any difference in the Obj-C code, but in the HTML I am trying to push data into a text field that is a data cell inside of a table.

Comment: Problem fixed.  I had the same id for the label of a text field as the text field.  Once I made them unique it worked!